# XML: words in a string of text are switching places in <h2>

Tags: xml

I've tried looking for the answer to this question, but as of yet no solution has worked. I have an **h2** element inside a block of XML code that is supposed to read "$100 Off Snow Blowers," but instead reads "Off Snow Blowers $100." If I take off the dollar sign, the number 100 just jumps to the end the same way. However, if I omit the space between $100 and Off, it displays correctly; it is also the case that if I replace $100 with alphabetic characters, it displays correctly. If I put another word in front of the $100 (e.g., "Special: $100 Off"), it stays where it's supposed to. I haven't been able to find any styling or other outside resources that should effect this, and the code around it seems to be constructed properly since it will display anything that isn't a special character or number.

---

Code:

```html
<h2 id="title60-white" class="title60">$100.00 Off Select Snow Throwers</h2>
```

---

Suggested solutions I have tried:

- Surrounding $100.00 in **price** tags
- Using various character entities to generate the space between $100 and Off
- Using the character entity for the dollar sign
- Removing the $
- Putting the $100 in a **span**
- Putting the entire string in a **div** inside the **h2**
- Putting the character entities into **spans**
- Tacking the $100 part on the other side of the alphabetic characters (because I was getting desperate!)

Thank you in advance for your assistance. I know I could just reword it or not be picky about the spacing, but I want the site to look the way it's supposed to and also want to know how to fix this if I hit a similar snag later.

Comment: The code you've posted works fine. Can you also post the code that doesn't work?

Comment: Unfortunately, the code snippet I provided above IS the one that doesn't work for me... I ended-up just changing the wording because it kept flip-flopping on me! Thank you for looking at it for me, though.

Comment: UPDATE: I think I figured out what was going on... I'd started out with a wacky template that had everything set to direction:rtl, and even though I'd corrected it at the body-level, and didn't see an rtl rule in the class attached to the element (or any parents), the behavior was still there. So, I added a direction:ltr rule into the class just to see what would happen, and it worked, so I guess it was just some unfortunate styling... Thanks again for offering to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My not-so-great starter template had the wacky elements stuck with a direction:rtl styling rule that made the punctuation jump around-- I don't know exactly "why" the code reacted the way it did to this, but when I put a rule in to reverse it, everything seemed to fall into place the right way.